# What solutions are available for generating video signal?

Tags: integrated-circuit, video

I'm looking for a video chip that could handle VGA resolution. 
It should be able to provide VGA, HDMI and Composite video out.
It needs to have some basic hardware acceleration eg. built in support for 80x25 text rendering, sprites.

What I have found:
Bitbang microcontroller libraries - either they don't provide HDMI or they requrire expensive microcontrollers.
MOS 8568 - the thing I'm looking for, but is no longer produced and has no HDMI.

I have looked at similar questions on stackexchange,but their about monochrome composite, which can be done with Arduino TVOut, or their about HD quality video.

Comment: You're not going to find a single chip that meets all of those requirements. Composite + VGA + 80x25 text + sprites are old-school technologies from the very earliest days of personal computers, while HDMI is a very new technology. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you building some sort of "retro" emulation system that can drive a modern flatscreen display?

Comment: @DaveTweed I saw a few very cheap ARM9 microcontrollers that could run linux and wanted to build a single-board computer less powerful, but cheaper than the RasPi A+.

Comment: Raspi is as cheap as you're going to get for HDMI, unless you repurpose a Chinese HDMI-on-a-stick.

Comment: OK. I understand HDMI is expensive if it isn't integrated on a chip. So what are the (cheap) solutions without HDMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI is kind of inaccessible to hobbyists; the signal requirements are quite tough. If your driving chip has a USB interface you could try http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/UFX6000-VE.pdf . Given the high data rate of HDMI, I don't think you're going to find a cheap solution. Built-in HDMI support on SoC is probably cheapest in terms of parts count.

Comment: HDMI does not actually have to be all that fast if the resolution if fairly low, and is in fact clearly within the range of the competent amateur. Granted that amateur has some decent tools and has read a few SI books, but a relatively cheap spartan 6 will manage it just using the IOSERDES, not at 4K60 (Which needs transceivers), but it will make pictures. The FPGA way is NOT cheap, but it can be made to work, I am unsure if a DMA capable parallel port and ADV7511 would have low enough jitter but it is possible it might be workable.